# Divide list when there is a shift from int to str

Tags: python, list

So I have a list that looks something like [’A’, 1, 3, 6, ’B’, 3, 5, ’C’, 6, 7, 3] how do I divide the list into sublists everytime there is a new string so that I would get [A’, 1, 3, 6] [’B’, 3, 5] [’C’, 6, 7, 3]

Comment: What should happen if there are no characters in list.

Answer (score 0):

Just look for a string character using regex and get all the substrings matching the criteria

```
import re
a=['A', 1, 3, 6, 'B', 3, 5, 'C', 6, 7, 3] 
l=re.findall('(\w\d{0,})',''.join(list(map(str,a))))
l=list(map(list,l))
for i in l:
    for index,j in enumerate(i):
        if j.isdigit():
            i[index]=int(j) #change type back to int for all the integers
print(l) #[['A', 1, 3, 6], ['B', 3, 5], ['C', 6, 7, 3]]
```

Comment: dict(map(lambda x:(x[0],list(map(int,x[1]))),re.findall("([a-zA-Z])(\d+)","".join(map(str,data)))))

Answer (score 0):

You could do this, but there's probably a more Pythonic way to do it:

```
my_list = ["A", 1, 3, 6, "B", 3, 5, "C", 6, 7, 3]

def is_number(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def sort_list(input_list):

    parent_list = []
    child_list = [input_list.pop(0)]

    while (len(input_list)):
        first = input_list.pop(0)

        if is_number(first):
            child_list.append(first)
        else: 
            parent_list.append(child_list)
            child_list = list(first)

    parent_list.append(child_list)

    return parent_list

print(sort_list(my_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple iterative loop

```
//original list is called x

x = ['A', '1', '3', '6', 'B', '3', '5', 'C', '6', '7', '3']
finallist = []
newList = []
addtolist = False 
for i in range (len(x)):
    if x[i].isalpha():
        if len(newList) != 0:
            finallist.append(newList)
            newList = []        
    newList.append(x[i])
finallist.append(newList)
print (finallist)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [’A’, 1, 3, 6, ’B’, 3, 5, ’C’, 6, 7, 3]
sub_list = []
count = -1

for i in my_list:
    if (isinstance(i, str)):
        count+=1
        l = [i]
        sub_list.append(l)

    else:
        if (count is -1):
            count+=1

        sub_list[count].append(i)
```

This will give you a list of list separated by `'a string'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
given = ['A', 1, 3, 6, 'B', 3, 5, 'C', 6, 7, 3]
result = []
current = []
for element in given:
    if type(element)==str:
        if current!=[]:
            result.append(current)
        current = []
    current.append(element)
result.append(current)
print(result)
```

prints out:

```
[['A', 1, 3, 6], ['B', 3, 5], ['C', 6, 7, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming order is not preference: you can use `collections.defaultdict`

```
>>> my_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
>>> key = ''
>>> for x in range(len(data)):
...     if str(data[x]).isalpha():
...         key = data[x]
...     elif str(data[x]).isnumeric():
...         my_dict[key].append(data[x])
...
>>> my_dict
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'C': [6, 7, 3], 'A': [1, 3, 6], 'B': [3, 5]})
```

Assuming order is preference:

```
>>> my_dict = collections.OrderedDict()
>>> key = ''
>>> for x in range(len(data)):
...     if str(data[x]).isalpha():
...         key = data[x]
...         my_dict[key] = []
...     elif str(data[x]).isnumeric():
...         my_dict[key].append(data[x])
...
>>> my_dict
OrderedDict([('A', [1, 3, 6]), ('B', [3, 5]), ('C', [6, 7, 3])])
```